# Common celery workers for different clients having different DBs

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm using celery with django and am storing the task results in the DB.
I'm considering having a single set of workers reading messages from a single message broker. Now I can have multiple clients submitting celery tasks and each client will have tasks and their results created/stored in a different DB.
Even though the workers are common, they know which DB to operate upon for each task.

Can I have duplicate task ids generated because they were submitted by different clients pointing to different DBs?

Thanks,

Comment: Since celery is using uuid for task id, it is highly unlikely to have duplicate ids

Comment: Right. I was reading about uuid and was trying to see what goes into generating them and if we could have clashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually you will have duplicates. Many people ignore this issue because it is a "low probability", and then are surprised when it hits them. And then a story leaks how someone was logged into another uses Facebook account. If you require them to always be unique then you will have to prefix each ID with something that will never repeat - like current date and time with microseconds.

And if that is not good enough, because there still is a even tinier chance of a collision, you can create a small application that will generate those prefixes, and will add an counter (incremented after each hash request, and reset every couple seconds) to the date and microseconds. It will have to work in single-threaded mode, but this will be a guarantee to generate unique prefixes that won't collide.

Comment: Does your answer apply even for a single client (single DB) submitting tasks to the broker? I'm interested in knowing if there is something about submitting tasks from different clients (separate DB, code) to the same broker that increases the probability of collisions.

Comment: @ksrini Volume increases the probability of collision, as part of UUID comes from random (and volume counter random). What beside random is taken into account when generating UUID depends on the system running it and implementation, so there is no one answer.

Comment: Thanks. `What beside random is taken into account when generating UUID depends on the system running it and implementation` That makes sense. So I'm guessing if the volumes are high enough for single client (DB) that submits tasks from multiple servers, then there is a chance of collisions with the UUID.

Comment: @ksrini you are correct in that assumption. Until recently most developers ignored that issue because of it's a long shot. They don't do anymore, because that specific issue caused people, who visit a website for very first time, be logged in as a random user (sometimes even an admin user!). Why? Because there was a collision in session_id.

Comment: @ksrini btw if I have helped you, feel free to upvote!

Comment: Done. I am just waiting to see if I get any other answers before I accept yours.